# Flutter app when runs returns a blank screen

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am working on a flutter app when i run this app this just returns me a blank screen

Here is the code for the main.dart file which has the firebase authentication code

```html
***main.dart***

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multi_purpose_scope/HomePage.dart';
import 'package:multi_purpose_scope/PatientList.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'AuthenticationService.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) => context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      return HomePage();
    }
    return PatientList();
  }
}
```

This is the code for the login page mainly the design view of the app and its on click function which
navigates to other activities

```html
 

***HomePage.dart***

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'Animation/FadeAnimation.dart';
import 'AuthenticationService.dart';
import 'ForgotPassword.dart';
import 'PatientList.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 400,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage('assets/images/loginHeader.png'),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FadeAnimation(
                          1.8,
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .2),
                                      blurRadius: 20.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 10))
                                ]),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border(
                                          bottom: BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.grey[100]))),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: emailController,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                        hintText: "Email or Phone number",
                                        hintStyle:
                                        TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400])),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: passwordController,
                                    obscureText: true,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                        hintText: "Password",
                                        hintStyle:
                                        TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400])),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 100, right: 100, top: 20, bottom: 20),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0),
                            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          gotoPatientList(BuildContext context) {
                            context.read<AuthenticationService>().signIn(
                              email: emailController.text.trim(),
                              password: passwordController.text.trim(),
                            );
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => PatientList()),
                            );
                          }
                          gotoPatientList(context);
                        },
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Text("Login".toUpperCase(),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                      ),
                      ClipOval(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            gotoForgotPassword(BuildContext context) {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => ForgotPassword()),
                              );
                            }
                            gotoForgotPassword(context);
                          },
                          child: Text("Forgot Password"),
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      return HomePage();
    }
    return PatientList();
  }
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```html
2021-02-16 18:19:30.953 21904-21904/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-02-16 18:19:30.954 21904-21904/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
2021-02-16 18:19:30.955 21904-21904/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
2021-02-16 18:19:30.958 21904-21904/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-G935T_8.0.0_0017, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
2021-02-16 18:19:30.959 21904-21904/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope 
2021-02-16 18:19:30.968 21904-21904/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-02-16 18:19:31.053 21904-21904/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled: cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
2021-02-16 18:19:31.054 21904-21904/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
2021-02-16 18:19:31.126 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/zygote64: no shared libraies, dex_files: 1
2021-02-16 18:19:31.194 21904-21924/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2021-02-16 18:19:31.215 21904-21927/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2021-02-16 18:19:31.226 21904-21923/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
2021-02-16 18:19:31.230 21904-21923/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:19 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:45
2021-02-16 18:19:31.231 21904-21923/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite, version >= 45
2021-02-16 18:19:31.232 21904-21923/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
2021-02-16 18:19:31.245 21904-21927/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
2021-02-16 18:19:31.245 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( UvIJfW4TZZQM3nIETraMvnjAXdt2 ).
2021-02-16 18:19:31.252 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2021-02-16 18:19:31.260 21904-21923/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope W/ResourceType: ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 67, previously 69
2021-02-16 18:19:31.260 21904-21923/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope W/ResourceType: ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 5486, previously 5487
2021-02-16 18:19:31.263 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/System.out: should load native is true
2021-02-16 18:19:31.265 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-02-16 18:19:31.277 21904-21932/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/ResourceExtractor: Found extracted resources res_timestamp-1-1613478813305
2021-02-16 18:19:31.285 21904-21923/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/DynamiteLoaderV2Impl: [71] Measurementdynamite
2021-02-16 18:19:31.295 21904-21923/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
2021-02-16 18:19:31.342 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 1b7798b, I8a9bdcf8d3
    Build Date                       : 03/15/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.22.00.01
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.6.5.R1.08.00.00.312.043
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2021-02-16 18:19:31.344 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8996.so from the current namespace instead.
2021-02-16 18:19:31.350 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
2021-02-16 18:19:31.468 21904-21943/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 38002
2021-02-16 18:19:31.468 21904-21943/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2021-02-16 18:19:31.470 21904-21943/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope
2021-02-16 18:19:31.625 21904-21951/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2021-02-16 18:19:31.635 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/ViewRootImpl@a1b73ed[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@150c222[MainActivity] TM=true MM=false
2021-02-16 18:19:31.650 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope V/InputMethodManager: Not IME target window, ignoring
2021-02-16 18:19:31.651 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/ViewRootImpl@a1b73ed[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2021-02-16 18:19:31.679 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
2021-02-16 18:19:31.683 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/ViewRootImpl@a1b73ed[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 483817242624} changed=true
2021-02-16 18:19:31.684 21904-21951/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2021-02-16 18:19:31.684 21904-21951/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2021-02-16 18:19:31.698 21904-21951/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope
2021-02-16 18:19:31.700 21904-21951/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x70a51c3df0
2021-02-16 18:19:31.705 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/SurfaceView: BG show() Surface(name=Background for - SurfaceView - com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope.MainActivity@5dcde6e@0) io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{5dcde6e V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,1920}
2021-02-16 18:19:31.719 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
2021-02-16 18:19:31.719 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/SurfaceView: surfaceCreated 1 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{5dcde6e V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,1920}
2021-02-16 18:19:31.747 21904-21943/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2021-02-16 18:19:31.793 21904-21909/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=20KB
2021-02-16 18:19:31.794 21904-21909/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=28KB, data=20KB
2021-02-16 18:19:31.794 21904-21909/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
2021-02-16 18:19:31.846 21904-21944/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:39889/K2QV5KtbiFM=/
2021-02-16 18:19:32.042 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/SurfaceView: surfaceChanged (1080,1920) 1 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{5dcde6e V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,1920}
2021-02-16 18:19:32.055 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/ViewRootImpl@a1b73ed[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
2021-02-16 18:19:32.055 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/ViewRootImpl@a1b73ed[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
2021-02-16 18:19:32.057 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@291f7d2 nm : com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope ic=null
2021-02-16 18:19:32.057 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2021-02-16 18:19:32.079 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/ViewRootImpl@a1b73ed[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x3 surface={valid=true 483817242624} changed=false
2021-02-16 18:19:32.095 21904-21951/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8996.so from the current namespace instead.
2021-02-16 18:19:32.105 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@14b0a3 nm : com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope ic=null
2021-02-16 18:19:34.854 21904-21935/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/libGLESv2: STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope
2021-02-16 18:20:02.894 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/ViewRootImpl@a1b73ed[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
2021-02-16 18:20:03.475 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/ViewRootImpl@a1b73ed[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
2021-02-16 18:20:03.820 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/ViewRootImpl@a1b73ed[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
2021-02-16 18:20:04.402 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/ViewRootImpl@a1b73ed[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
2021-02-16 18:21:10.112 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/ViewRootImpl@a1b73ed[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
2021-02-16 18:21:10.144 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/SurfaceView: BG show() Surface(name=Background for - SurfaceView - com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope.MainActivity@5dcde6e@0) io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{5dcde6e V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920}
2021-02-16 18:21:10.148 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/SurfaceView: surfaceDestroyed 1 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{5dcde6e V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920}
2021-02-16 18:21:10.163 21904-21909/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=55KB, data=39KB
2021-02-16 18:21:10.172 21904-21909/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=55KB, data=39KB
2021-02-16 18:21:10.172 21904-21909/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
2021-02-16 18:21:10.198 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/SurfaceView: BG show() Surface(name=Background for - SurfaceView - com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope.MainActivity@5dcde6e@0) io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{5dcde6e V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920}
2021-02-16 18:21:10.215 21904-21951/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x70a51c3df0
2021-02-16 18:21:10.228 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/ViewRootImpl@a1b73ed[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
2021-02-16 18:21:10.278 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope D/ViewRootImpl@a1b73ed[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={valid=false 0} changed=false
2021-02-16 18:21:10.858 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@93de6a6 nm : com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope ic=null
2021-02-16 18:21:10.858 21904-21904/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
```

I searched alot for my problem but can't seem to find the solution to my problem.My guess is it has something to do with the navigation widget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the most important part

> runApp()

This is used to attach your widget to the screen.

This would help:

```
      Future<void> main() async {
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        await Firebase.initializeApp();

        runApp(MyApp());
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call **runApp();** in main function

```
   main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(MyApp ()); // add this line
    }
```